# Nginx 80 with Primary Domain works fine, Why does Apache2 8080 with sub domain doesn't work(400 Bad Reques from 80 port)?

Tags: apache, nginx

I would like to run two website in one server, www.domain.com with 80 port of `nginx`, and sub.domain.com with 8080 port of `apache2`

Now `nginx in port 80` works fine(both ip address and www.domain.com), I can visit `apache2 in port 8080` only ip address(only localhost:8080 works), but when I clicked sub.domain.com, I get a 400 Bad Request, I noticed it still was running in 80 port.

It's weird I already changed `80` into `8080` in file of `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`

And below is partial codes of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName sub.domain.com
        <Directory "/var/www/html">
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ........
<VirtualHost>
```

So is there something wrong with `Apache2`? www.domain.com with 80 port of `nginx` works fine, do I need to change the configuration of `nginx`? I pasted all code of `/etc/nginx/sites-available/www.domain.com` as below:

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/wtf/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen 80;

    # add here the ip address of your server
    # or a domain pointing to that ip (like example.com or www.example.com)
    server_name www.domain.com;

    keepalive_timeout 5;
    client_max_body_size 1G;

    access_log /home/wtf/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/wtf/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/wtf/donthack/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/wtf/donthack/media/;
    }

    # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you visited `sub.domain.com:8080` or `sub.domain.com` ? Because `domain.com` is alias for `domain.com:80`

Comment: Hi, I visited both `sub.domain.com:8080` (Nothing) and `sub.domain.com`(400 Bad Request), `domain.com` is alias for domain.com:80? No wonder I've already set sub.domain.com with port 8080 in Apache2, but when I visit `sub.domain.com`, it still was in port 80 with nginx(400 Bad Request), localhost:8080 works fine, do you know how to solve this issue? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have you restarted apache server process?
   A service-reload is not enough to change listening port. You can use **`lsof -i TCP:8080 -s TCP:LISTEN`** to ensure httpd process is listening at you new port.
2. Have you included **`NameVirtualHost *:8080`** in your conf, in case the apache version is low?

Comment: Hi, yes, I've already restarted apache server process, and  executed `lsof -i TCP:8080 -s TCP:LISTEN` just now, then restarted apache server again, `sub.domain.com` still appeared 400 Bad Request in 80 port of `Nginx`, I executed `netstat -tlpn` again and again since yesterday, I ensure `tcp6 in 8080 of apache2` and `tcp in 80 of nginx`

Comment: Hi, I've included <VirtualHost *:8080> in my default conf, did you mean I need to change `VirtualHost` into `NameVirtualHost` ?

Comment: What is the output of **`lsof -i TCP:8080 -s TCP:LISTEN`**?

Comment: `COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2 9757     root    4u  IPv6 179829      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2 9761 www-data    4u  IPv6 179829      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2 9762 www-data    4u  IPv6 179829      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2 9763 www-data    4u  IPv6 179829      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2 9764 www-data    4u  IPv6 179829      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2 9765 www-data    4u  IPv6 179829      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
`

Comment: You can add **`NameVirtualHost *:8080`** under **`Listen 8080`**, then restart Apache Server.

Comment: Hi, I got a error `AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/ports.conf:6`, now I know `domain.com` is alias for `domain.com:80` so `sub.domain.com` is default 80 port too, right? that's the reason why I visited `sub.domain.com:8080` but got 400 Bad Request of `Nginx 80`, I changed another domain1.com, now domain.com:8080 works fine There is nothing wrong with my configuration.